# Any way to check if TCP socket in NodeJS has been connected

Tags: node.js

Any way to check if TCP socket in NodeJS has been connected.
As opposed to still connecting in transient.
Am looking for a property as opposed to an emitted event.
Is it even possible?

Comment: My initial answer was that there were no ways to do it without events but I edited it as there is an undocumented way to do it. I strongly advise against it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The manual](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connect) shows you that an event is emitted for when the connection is established and that is how you should handle it the Node.js way (using non-blocking, asynchronous i/o)

There is though an undocumented way to check it, the socket object has a `_connecting` boolean property that if set to false means it has been connected already or failed.

Example :

```
var net = require('net');

//Connect to localhost:80
var socket = net.createConnection(80);

if(socket._connecting === true) {
    console.log("The TCP connection is not established yet");
}
```

Comment: how to test if it is connected?